# Generic: Version number bit shift routine

Tags: java, c++, algorithm

I would like the best routine the community can devise which will provide a version number string using only 32 bits. The version number will contain three parts: major, minor, and build number. Bonus karma points for answers that include Java source.

**Update 1**

Ok, so to clear up some confusion the major and minor fields should be represented with one 8-bit byte each and the build number would use the remaining bits.
Major: 8 bits
Minor: 8 bits
Build: 16 bits
The byte order will be little endian.

The tags are to denote that an answer in java and / or c++ would be preferred over python, ruby, etc..

**Update 2**

Example: take an integer (4 bytes) like 101020 and run it through an algormithmic routine to produce an output string like so: 0.1.2

**Java Solution**

```
    public static final int versionToInt(int major, int minor, int build) {
        int ver = (major << 24) | (minor << 16) | build;
    return ver;
    }

    public static final String versionToString(int ver) {
        return String.format("%s.%s.%s", ((ver & 0xff000000) >> 24), ((ver & 0x00ff0000) >> 16), (ver & 0x0000ffff));
    }
```

Comment: Why have you tagged this as C++ as well?

Comment: `struct { unsigned char major, minor; unsigned short build; };`?

Comment: This is not a well-specified question.  How many bits for each field?

Comment: Is there a comparable answer on stack? I looked and I cannot remember the routine we used to use in source 7 years ago. My question is not just to help me but others as well.

Comment: Have a look here: http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/BitSet.html

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Java:

```
class Version
{
    public char major;
    public char minor;
    public short build;

    // And the rest of your class definition ...
}
```

Edit:  So you want to do it with a bit shifts and store it in a 32-bit integer (even though using a class or struct would still use the same amount of storage space)?

An example function in C would be as follows

```
uint32_t MakeVersionNumber( int8_t major, int8_t minor, int16_t build )
{
   return ((uint32_t)major << 24) | ((uint32_t)minor << 16) | ((uint32_t)build);
}
```

Edit 2:

Riiight I think i get ya.  You have a 32-bit number and you want to get a string.  So here is an example in C++:

```
std::string MakeVersionString( unsigned int ver )
{
    std::stringstream ss;
    ss << ((ver & 0xff000000) >> 24) << "." << ((ver & 0x00ff0000) >> 16) << "." << (ver & 0x0000ffff);
    return ss.str(); 
}
```

Comment: Where's the bit shifting? with this example how would 10201 become soemthing like 0.1.2?

Comment: @Mondain: Where are you getting the number 10201 from? Just let `major` be zero, `minor` be one, and `build` be two.

Comment: The int given was an example due to the fact that I am no expert in bit shifting routines. Thanks for the updated answer.

Comment: @Mondain: also note in C++ and Java, the bit shifting is in base 2, not base 10.  So "0.1.2" would be 0*2^24+1*2^16+2 = 65538 as an integer, and 100.200.123 would be 100*2^24+200*2^16+123 = 1690828923 as an integer.  Saves space.